# Library functions vs Java methods in Clojure

Tags: java, function, clojure

While reading 'Programming Clojure', I noticed that there are alternative ways to perform some operations in Clojure. For example, let's say we need to convert all characters of a string to their upper-case variants.

We can use `.toUpperCase`:

```
user> (.toUpperCase "foo")
;; => "FOO"
```

As well as `clojure.string/upper-case`:

```
user> (clojure.string/upper-case "foo")
;; => "FOO"
```

While `clojure.string/upper-case` is a function and we can treat it as such:

```
user> (map clojure.string/upper-case ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
;; => ("FOO" "BAR" "BAZ")
```

...we cannot do the same with `.toUpperCase`:

```
user> (map .toUpperCase ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol...
```

I guess that `.toUpperCase` is direct call of Java method, and Clojure knows how to deal with this symbol when it is first element of a form.

**Q**: what should I use `.toUpperCase` or `clojure.string/upper-case` and what's difference between:

```
(map clojure.string/upper-case ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
```

and

```
(map (fn [x] (.toUpperCase x)) ["foo" "bar" "baz"])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either works: it's basically a trade-off as follows:

Advantages of wrapped Clojure functions:

- More idiomatic Clojure style
- More likely to be portable (e.g. to ClojureScript)
- Can be passed to higher order functions

Advantages of using Java methods:

- Slightly better performance (assuming you use type hints correctly to avoid reflection)
- More transparent if you are working with Java programmers / Java code bases

Normally, I prefer to use wrapped Clojure functions, unless I have benchmarked and identified a performance problem, at which point I might drop down to direct Java interop.

Answer (score 7):

`clojure.string/upper-case` is just a wrapper function of `java.lang.String.toUpperCase` method. You can check in in your repl.

```
user=> (source clojure.string/upper-case)
(defn ^String upper-case
  "Converts string to all upper-case."
  {:added "1.2"}
  [^CharSequence s]
  (.. s toString toUpperCase))
```

As you can see, `upper-case` just invoke `toUpperCase`.

I don't think there's any strong rule to choose only one between them. However, as you already know, `.toUpperCase` method is not a clojure function and cannot be passed as an argument to other higher order functions. So, it would be better to use `clojure.string/upper-case`, if you don't have any specific reasons to use `.toUpperCase` method.